# Using Charles proxy to decrypt googleapis.com

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm writing a app, which makes use of Google Play Services. I want to see that what all data is sent over to googleapis.com. I'm using Charles tool to intercept the data using SSL Proxy. But for some reason it doesn't seem to work for www.googleapis.com, android.googleapis.com. However, for other domains but above, I was able to see plain text data successfully. So, I know that I got SSL proxy in Charles configured right. I've followed this link to set up: [here](http://jaanus.com/blog/2012/02/12/debugging-http-on-an-android-phone-or-tablet-with-charles-proxy-for-fun-and-profit/)

Does anyone got it working so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think Google may be using another protocol like SPDY rather than HTTP for their docs. That might be a reason why this occurs.