# Frida and Charles can't inspect requests to firestore.googleapis.com

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-api, charles-proxy, frida

I know this question is very similar to this one: [Using Charles proxy to decrypt googleapis.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21739445/10574428),
but it is very old and I think google changed some stuff about their APIs.

I'm using Charles to inspect HTTP requests from an android app (which is not mine).
This app uses SSL pinning, so I bypassed it with this tutorial:
https://lucy-janewalsh.com/blog/2019/10/29/unpinning-an-app

This works perfectly for every domain, except firestore.googleapis.com.

Charles gives me this error:

> No request was made. Possibly the SSL certificate was rejected.

Do you know if this is possible to inspect requests made to this address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial only disables SSLPinning by the conscrypt library and only if the app that uses this library has not been obfuscated. If the app is obfuscated the class can not be found and the pinning will remain active. Also keep in mind that conscrypt is based on my experience not very often used by Android apps. Other libraries that provide SSLPinning like OKHttp are way more often used (e.g. covered by [this Frida snippet](https://codeshare.frida.re/@masbog/frida-android-unpinning-ssl/).

In your case everything depends on the app you try to intercept the traffic of. Decompile it e.g. using [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) or your favorite app decompiler and try to identify the used library/method for SSL pinning. If the app is obfuscated (class names changed) then most likly you have to write your own frida code to disable pinning (or at least adapt the class names form an existing frida code snippet that performs unpinning for the SSL-library used in your app).

Comment: thanks for your answer! But if i'm getting it right, you are saying that those requests can't be decrypted because the frida script doesn't fix the right things. But the problem is that every domain, except firestore, can actually be decrypted perfectly. Maybe the app uses different technologies for standard web requests and for firestore requests? (it's a react native app).

Comment: If the app uses different HTTP-client libraries this would be possible explanation (or the same library with different configs, one with and one without pinning). As I said you have to decompile the app to understand the details what clients are when used.